# list not showing when debugging on device

Tags: android, sqlite, apache-flex, flash-builder

am using flash builder to develop mobile app that has local SQLite database that is connected and working great on the desktop debugger of flash builder, but when i tried to run the app on actual device the app load but the list is empty ,although i have +100 records in my SQlite database.

how to keep the list from being empty in actual device ?

these are the permissions in myapp.xml

```
<android>
<colorDepth>16bit</colorDepth>
<manifestAdditions><![CDATA[

<manifest>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

</manifest>

  ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

strange thing is i didn't get any error

Comment: How did you get data into your database to start with?  Are you deploying the database with the application?

Answer (score 0):

found the answer

just had to change File.documentDirectory.resolvePath("ff.db");

to File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("ff.db");